# expressions in lambda calculus

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, computation-theory

am trying HARD AND FAILING  to find how to express a question in Lambda..

Perhaps am mistaken in the search?
As far as I understand, in Lambda calculus, we get to define the parameters, operations, etc.
eg:
    TRUE := λx.λy.x
    FALSE := λx.λy.y
    AND := λp.λq.p q p
    OR := λp.λq.p p q
etc..

Am wondering how, even theoretically, there is a way to compute a question with lambda.

i.e. an anonnymous/abstract question like:

QUESTION := The_Lambda_expression

What might compute as a question - there must be a function, no??

Any ideas? Clues?

Cheers and Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "a question"? A conditional (like "if-then-else") or something else?

Comment: i mean that something is unknown. Like, did i like that soup? I don't know. It's an open question in my mind... Something the program keep pondering and wondering about. There must be a function for doing that, no?

Comment: How would you express "Did I like that soup?" in any other language? That does not really seem like a question that a computer program can answer.

Comment: i thought a computer can ask. is computation limited to answers only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems what you are looking for is **predicates**, which is nothing but a formal form of questions for which the response/answer is YES (True) or NO (False).

Check out the Logic and Predicate section at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Logic_and_predicates.

Comment: Many thanks - a fair point. Its not exactly what had in mind initially because am not thinking of booleans, yes/no, but wider possible (fuzzy?) questions.. Though perhaps doing the questions rather than the answers, or possible answer range, is beyond contemporary computation?

Answer (score 0):

Your latest comment makes me think that you want to know how to read user input (i.e. "ask the user a question"). If that's not what you meant, feel free to clarify further.

The lambda calculus has no concept of IO as such - only functions with parameters. So instead of asking the user for input, you'd write a function that takes the required information as its parameter(s).

Let's consider the following example: The user can order a meal that contains N pieces of meat and optionally a soup to go with it and we want to calculate the total price in dollars. Each piece of meat costs two dollars and the soup costs one. In order to represent this we write a function that takes the boolean `soup`, which represents whether the user wants soup, and the number `pieces_of_meat`, which represents how many pieces of meat the user wants:

```
λ soup. λ meat. meat * 2 + (soup 0 1)
```